# Database wont attach to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to attach a database to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I have moved the `.MDF` file into `C:\programfiles\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Data`

It shows up when I go to the attach screen but I get this error message when I hit 'OK' on the attach screen:

> Attach database failed for Server 'DESKTOP-5DHLE7T\sqlexpress'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> Additional information:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.). (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5133)

My instructions say to attach the database to `C:\programfiles\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data` . However despite completing the exact same installation as the guide I don't have a `MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER` path, only the `C:\programfiles\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Data` like I stated earlier.

Is this where my problem lies? If so, where should I be putting the `.MDF` file before I attach it? Any ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you put it (but data hygiene and backup procedures will probably make the choice obvious..)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are attaching the files to your database server, not Management Studio.

Second, your error is about a log file missing. You actually don´t need the LDF just to attach the file, but you need to do some work to make it happen:

```
USE [master] GO
-- Method 1: I use this method
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='TestDb',
@physname=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\YourDBFile.mdf'
GO
```

Or, you can also do this:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDb ON
(FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\YourDBFile.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

Comment: I tried both of your solutions, replaced the path, and got "Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLexpress\MSSQL\DATA\Adventureworks2012_Data.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3"                                                                                                                   Like I said the only directory there is MSSQL10.SQLExpress for some reason there is no MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER. But I still got that error when I replaced the path in your code

Comment: You have to use your actual path. What is in the sample is just sample data. Try moving the file you wanna attach to another location

Comment: I used the actual path.Ill try putting it somewhere else. Lots of stuff I found points to it being a security thing. Thanks a ton for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying the LDF file is missing. You need both the MDF and the LDF.

Comment: You actually don't need the LDF file, you just need to delete the auto-filled ldf file name before you perform the attach.

Comment: Thanks! Google wasn't much help, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can click the second file with type is LDF and hit "Remove"